# If the Weyl group $\mathcal W$ is a normal subgroup of $\mathrm{Aut}(\Phi)$, how can the Weyl group of $A_2$ be dihedral of order $6$?

Tags: lie-algebras, root-systems, weyl-group

> [image]

---

If the Weyl group $\mathcal W$ is a normal subgroup of $\mathrm{Aut}(\Phi)$, how can the Weyl group of $A_2$ be dihedral of order $6$?

The roots of $A_2$ are $\{\pm \alpha, \pm \beta, \pm(\alpha+\beta)\}$. So, $\mathrm{Aut}(\Phi) \cong S_6$. But, $S_6$ does not have a subgroup isomorphic to dihedral group of order $6$.

Comment: The dihedral group of order $6$ is isomorphic to $S_3$.

Comment: @BW. which is not a normal subgroup of $S_6$.

Comment: Oh, I thought you were just trying to see why it was a subgroup of $S_6$. Where are you getting the requirement that $W$ be normal in $\operatorname{Aut}(\Phi)$?

Comment: @BW. In Humphrey's book. Section 9 exercise 6. It is an exercise to show the Weyl group is a normal subgroup of $\mathrm{Aut}(\Phi)$. Is that result not stated correctly? Or am I not understanding something from the statement as stated?

Comment: I just checked, and I think it's worthwhile checking out the last lemma in section 9.2, (p 43 in my copy). It seems like $\operatorname{Aut}(\Phi)$ is not just permutations of $\Phi$ as a set, but the vector space automorphisms of the associated Euclidean space preserving $\langle,\rangle$ and leaving $\Phi$ invariant. Because then I think a direct computation does indeed show $W\unlhd\operatorname{Aut}(\Phi)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathrm{Aut}(\Phi)$, for $\Phi$ a root system of type $A_2$, is **not** isomorphic to $S_6$; it is the group of *linear* automorphisms, you cannot freely permute all roots. Rather, this automorphism group is actually the symmetry group of a hexagon (the hexagon formed by the endpoints of the roots), which is the dihedral group of order $12$, which is the direct product of the group of order $2$ and the dihedral group of order $6$; this second factor is the Weyl group, and being a direct factor, it's of course normal.